# crash on textfield click iOS 6.0 and xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I have made an app regarding rating of picture. It is working fine on iOS 5. Today, i have started updating the whole code and making it compatible with iPhone 5. Some XIB's has been updated but now I got crash whenever I click on uitextfield but all the uibutton action is working fine. I have just changed the XIB to iPhone Retina 4.0 display. Please if someone has an idea about it please let me know.

Comment: Does it still work against iOs 5 ?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine on iOS 5

Comment: What does crash log says

Comment: No, it crashes without giving any error or crash log

Comment: If you can't give the reply to my problem then no need to give it negative points.

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you see in the debugger and/or console when the crash occurs?  Help us help you.  'I see nothing' is not an acceptable response.

Comment: Find any solution ? I am also stuck in iOS 5 to iOS 6 change :(

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that **"auto-correction", "auto-capitalization" and "check-spelling"** properties of UITextField set to its default values in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in the code that gets executed when you click on the text field and see where it crashes. You can then post the code here to get ideas.